How to use (or mimic) the behaviour of `satisfies` in a function argument?
I am trying to create a function that accepts a generic type and preserves the literal values of its contents, but does not allow any extra keys.
The typescript satisfies keyword does exactly what I need - but from what I can see it is only possible to use it while defining a literal type rather than as a function argument.
Here is a bare-bones example of what I mean:
type Foo = { a: number };

const foo = <T extends Foo>(x: T) => x;

foo({ a: 1, wrong: 2 }) // typechecks, but i don't want it to

foo({ a: 1, wrong: 2} satisfies Foo) // causes the type error i want


I've tried all sorts of acrobatics to get this to work to no avail. However after posting a feature request on the Typescript repo I've been pointed to a new feature of Typescript that has allowed me to get something working (see comment).
The solution I ended up with was this monstrosity:
type OptionalKeys<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    [P in keyof T]: {} extends Pick<T, P> ? P : never;
}[keyof T];

type RequiredKeys<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    [P in keyof T]: {} extends Pick<T, P> ? never : P;
}[keyof T];

type Satisfies<T, Base> =
    // recur if both the generic type and its base are records
    T extends Record<string, unknown>
        ? Base extends Record<string, unknown>
            // this check is to make sure i don't intersect with {}, allowing any keys
            ? (keyof T & RequiredKeys<Base> extends never
                  ? unknown
                  : {
                        [K in keyof T & RequiredKeys<Base>]: Satisfies<
                            T[K],
                            Base[K]
                        >;
                    }) &
                   // this check is to make sure i don't intersect with {}, allowing any keys
                  (keyof T & OptionalKeys<Base> extends never
                      ? unknown
                      : {
                            [K in keyof T & OptionalKeys<Base>]?: Satisfies<
                                T[K],
                                Base[K]
                            >;
                        })
            // if the generic type is a record but the base type isn't, something has gone wrong
            : never
        : T extends (infer TE)[]
          ? Base extends (infer BE)[]
              ? Satisfies<TE, BE>[]
               // if the generic type is an array but the base type isn't, something has gone wrong
              : never
          // the type is a scalar so no need to recur
          : T;

Here is a ts playground that demonstrates this solution in action, by causing the correct errors for the following examples:
type Foo = { a: { b?: number }[] };

const foo = <T extends Foo>(x: Satisfies<T, Foo>) => x;

foo({ a: [{}] }); // typechecks
foo({ a: [{ b: 3 }] }); // typechecks
foo({ x: 2 }); // error
foo({ a: [{}], x: 2 }); // error
foo({ a: [{ b: 2, x: 3 }] }); // error
foo({ a: [{ x: 3 }] }); // error


Any suggestions on how to clean this up or otherwise improve it would be extremely appreciated! I'm well out of my comfort zone with this.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your code to be a self-contained [mre] (pls click and read) that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and see what you're seeing. Right now this seems to be an excerpt of some larger code base that we don't have access to, so if we try to look at it we get lots of errors unrelated to your problem.  If something weird is happening with publishing declaration files, we need enough information to debug that too, since it sounds like you found a solution but you ran into a subsequent problem.

thanks @jcalz , have updated the question as requested. have also added a partial solution i've come up with based on some pointers given to me in an issue on the typescript github. have left this question unanswered for now though in case anyone has a better solution than my very very very messy one.

You're running into issues because you're fighting against the TS type system. Why do you care about excess properties so much? Is your code going to explode if you pass in something with excess properties? You need a recursive prohibition on excess properties? Then it's going to be complicated. Until and unless exact types as per ms/TS#12936 are implemented, you'll have this issue. I might be able to write something simpler, I'll see what I can come up with.

i don't care about excess properties as such, the actual runtime values can contain extra properties and the code will handle it - this is more of a linting / user experience concern, to make it easier for callers to write correct code

That makes less sense than before. Why would const foo = <T extends Foo>(x: T) => x; make it hard to write correct code? IntelliSense prompts the whole time for the expected properties. And the only times you'd need errors is if you forget required properties, or give them the wrong types. If excess properties don't matter, what's the point of the question?

Maybe as a vim user I am more sensitive than others to the possibility of accidentally circumventing intellisense suggestions :-)
Excess properties matter when you have an optional property called something like username and you unintentionally provide an "excess" property called something like userName. No type error, but it's definitely not doing what you think it's doing, and it feels like the kind of thing that could be caught by a type system.

If you are interested (and I appreciate you've already spent a lot of time on this) the (very much work in progress) code for what I'm trying to do is public, and can be found here, in the type-refactor branch https://github.com/casekit/orm/tree/type-refactor. In particular there is a motivating example in this file: https://github.com/casekit/orm/blob/69ea456bd0f66323f94a6257e4187bc48236ed0f/src/test/fixtures/index.ts. x typechecks and shouldn't, y causes a type error (because of satisfies) - which is the behaviour I want to achieve.

It's not that I'm not interested, but I'm not going to spend time navigating away from SO to look at code. Does this version work for you better than your current one? If so I'll write up an answer, but... well... you're looking for exact types. You really are. From here and from your GitHub issue it's clear that you want that feature, but for some reason you think you don't. I don't know how to help if we can't agree on that; you want to prohibit excess properties. Can we agree on that? Or should we just chalk it up to a communication impasse?

That version looks great, thank you for your help! Happy to mark it as the accepted answer if you'd like to post it as one. I've read through the exact types issue several times now and I just cannot see how it describes what I want, whereas the behaviour of satisfies on a const assignment does do exactly (pun not intended) what I want. However I think the most likely thing at this point, rather than a communication impasse, is that I have some fundamental missing piece of understanding. As I said on the Github issue, maybe it'll make sense as I continue to learn . Thanks again!

You're looking for so-called "exact types" (terminology is from Flow) where excess properties are considered errors.  See microsoft/TypeScript#12936. TypeScript doesn't support these; all of its types are "inexact" to allow for structural typing. There is a feature that warns on excess properties in object literals in some situations, but this is more of a linter warning and is not actually part of the type system.
You can use generics to simulate exact types by wring something like T extends Exactly<T, U> which will only work if T is "exactly" U, meaning it doesn't have any extra properties. You seem to care about this recursively, so we can write a DeepExactly<T, U> where all objectlike properties of T are checked "exactly" against the properties of U.
Here's one way to write this:
type DeepExactly<T, U> =
    T extends object ? U extends object ?
    { [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof U ? DeepExactly<T[K], U[K]> : never } :
    never : U

We're basically using mapped types to convert any excess properties to never, which is very likely not to be compatible.  Let's test it out:
type Foo = { a: { b?: number }[] };
const foo = <T extends Foo>(x: T extends DeepExactly<T, Foo> ? T : DeepExactly<T, Foo>) => x;

foo({ a: [{}] }); // typechecks
foo({ a: [{ b: 3 }] }); // typechecks
foo({ x: 2 }); // error
foo({ a: [{}], x: 2 }); // error
foo({ a: [{ b: 2, x: 3 }] }); // error
foo({ a: [{ x: 3 }] }); // error

Looks good!
Note that this isn't foolproof. TypeScript really cannot model exact types, so nothing whatsoever can ever, even in principle, stop this:
const x = { a: [{ b: 3, e: "haha" }], b: "hello", c: "whoopsiedoodle" };
const y: Foo = x;
foo(y) // okay

In order for that to be prevented, you'd need a type that was Exact<Foo> or DeepExact<Foo> that would literally prohibit excess properties. Which is why microsoft/TypeScript#12936 is still open.
Playground link to code
