TypeScript: How to force Generic type that extends Record<..,..> to be of same type
I wrote a generic type to handle my validations. Here is a simple exemple to describe how it works
type User = { name: string; cars: Car[] }
type Car = { name: string }

If I have an attribute in error, like name, I'm expecting an array of string to define those errors. Also, the error object can only contains property that belongs to the validated type. The property is not present if there is no errors for that property.
errors = { name: ["is required"] }

When the error is in a nested association, i'm expecting an array of the association with same structure for attribute inside.
errors = { cars: [{name: ["is required"]] }

Actual Code
Here are my types:
type FormErrors<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  [K in keyof Partial<T>]: T[K] extends Record<string, unknown>[] ? Array<FormErrors<T[K][number]>> : Array<string>;
};

Usage
let errors: FormErrors<User>;

errors.name // string[] | undefined
errors.cars // FormErrors<Car>[] | undefined

Problem
Right now, TypeScript doesn't enforce the value of my Generic type. Let's say I have a method that expects to receive FormErrors<User>, it will let me pass FormErrors<Car> without any warning.
How can this be solved?
I understand Typescript that this is happening because they have attribute in commons, but can this be helped?
Playground

You want exact types but TS doesn't have them. This is essentially the same situation as [in this question]https://stackoverflow.com/q/78259909/2887218) and if I use the solution from there I get this playground link. It gets you a bit closer but still does not and cannot prohibit someone widening FormErrors<User> to FormErrors<Car>. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?
